# Regular Expression Validation for a Phone no that will accept nos,dashes and +

Tags: regex

I just need a Regular Expression that will validate a phone no entered in the textbox. That textbox can allow only numbers,dashes(-) and plus(+) and should be maximum of 15 characters and minimum of 11 characters.
(+) can(Optional) only come at starting of phone no.

Please answer.

Comment: You can't have a +Code-zip-num-berx in 13 characters.. why the character maximum?

Comment: you need to specify the language which you are using..regex implementation differs in many languages..

Answer (score 1):

Your question is answered by this:

```
\+?[\d-]{1,13}
```

- `\+?` means "zero of one '+' character"
- `[\d-]{1,13}` means "from 1 to 13 digits or hyphen"

However, I think you should use something a little more prescriptive. Perhaps requiring there's at least say 8 digits and the hyphen can't be first or last:

```
^(?=(.*\d){8,13})\+?(?!-)[\d-]*(?<!-)$
```

Comment: u can simply make it `{8,13}`

Comment: @Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It I suppose so. Yes - that's a good idea. Then I can just make the body `*`. See edited answer.

Answer (score -1):

Disregarding your 13 character constraint, you can use this regex:

`^((\+[0-9]([0-9]{2}|[1-9])?-)?([1-9][0-9]{2}-)?[1-9][0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4})?$`

Comment: Only an american would code a regex for an american phone number when the question doesn't mention America. Not all countries have 3-digit area codes - for example Australia has 2-digit ones - so your regex wouldn't work there.